# Extract regex groups from text with bash and output to file

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I need to scan a log file and extract the relevant parts from it to another file.
The log format is:

```
   [hh:mm:ss] Header
   [hh:mm:ss] irrelevant text
   [hh:mm:ss] irrelevant text
   [hh:mm:ss]Error text
   [hh:mm:ss] some details
   [hh:mm:ss] end_error;
   [hh:mm:ss] irrelevant text
   [hh:mm:ss] Warning text
   [hh:mm:ss] some details
   [hh:mm:ss] end_warning;
   [hh:mm:ss] irrelevant text
   [hh:mm:ss] irrelevant text
   [hh:mm:ss]Error text
   [hh:mm:ss] some details
   [hh:mm:ss] end_error;
```

I need to get all occurrences of Error and Warning and capture the following text:

```
[hh:mm:ss]Error text
[hh:mm:ss] some details
[hh:mm:ss] end_error;
[hh:mm:ss] Warning text
[hh:mm:ss] some details
[hh:mm:ss] end_warning;
[hh:mm:ss]Error text
[hh:mm:ss] some details
[hh:mm:ss] end_error;
```

What is the simplest way to achieve this on bash?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/^(Error|Warning)/{f=1} f; /;/{f=0}' file
Error text
end_error;
Warning text
end_warning;
```

Your original input file showed Error and Warning at the start of each line so my script above has a start-of-line anchor (^) in it. Using your latest posted sample input file and desired output you'd need:

```
$ awk '
   /^[[:space:]]*\[[^]]+\][[:space:]]*(Error|Warning)/ { found=1 }
   found { sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,""); print }
   /;/ { found=0 }
' file
[hh:mm:ss]Error text
[hh:mm:ss] some details
[hh:mm:ss] end_error;
[hh:mm:ss] Warning text
[hh:mm:ss] some details
[hh:mm:ss] end_warning;
[hh:mm:ss]Error text
[hh:mm:ss] some details
[hh:mm:ss] end_error;
```

The complexity of the regexp is to avoid false matches if the words Error or Warning appear elsewhere in your input file.

Comment: Hi Ed, this is what happens when people don't really understand awk. I already have headaches trying to apply your example on my real log, but I'm missing something.                                                                                    I kindly ask you to have a look on the real format of the log I've attached, since the first one was an oversimplification and I could not adapt your example on the real one.

Answer (score 1):

Using `GNU sed` range operator with `-n` and `-r` option to suppress default printing and enabling extended regular expression respectively. `p` flag prints the line that matches the condition.

```
$ sed -nr '/^(Error|Warning)/,/;/p' file
Error text
end_error;
Warning text
end_warning;
```

You can do the same in `awk` too. But using [Ed's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28801036/970195) approach is almost always recommended.

```
$ awk '/^(Error|Warning)/,/;/' file
Error text
end_error;
Warning text
end_warning;
```

Comment: Hi jaypal, I've tried for several hours to understand how to capture multiple lines with sed or awk but it seems like I'm missing something.                           Would you be so kind to take a look at the updated format of the log and adapt your example to work for my update?

Comment: Hi @Mark, no problem. The above solution will work. Just remove the anchor `^`. So `sed -nr '/(Error|Warning)/,/;/p' file` or  `awk '/(Error|Warning)/,/;/' file`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sh
cat file | awk '/^(Error|Warning)/,/;$/ { print $0 }' > output
```

This will pipe the file through awk, awk will print lines starting with `Error` or `Warning` up to the first line ending with `;`, the result will be saved on `output`

Comment: UUOC and unnecessary print and ranges are best avoided.